# Transform Object into JSON and remove keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having a few difficulties trying to make a new array out of existing Objects.  If I do the following

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data))
```

The output is like so

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {"id":1,"node":"0","name":"pizza","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"node":"1","name":"pasta","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":3,"node":"2","name":"pie","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"id":1,"source":"0","target":"1","value":"451","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"source":"1","target":"3","value":"237","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is from nodes, remove everything that is not node or name.  And from links, remove everything besides source, target and value.  I have been trying things like the following without success

```
const valuesToRemove = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
this.data.links = this.data.links.filter((i) => (valuesToRemove.indexOf(i) === -1));
```

So how would I go about turning the above into something like this?

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {"node":"0","name":"pizza"},
        {"node":"1","name":"pasta"},
        {"node":"2","name":"pie"}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"source":"0","target":"1","value":"451"},
        {"source":"1","target":"3","value":"237"}
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why remove what is uneeded, why not just keep what is needed? Try this: `this.data.nodes = this.data.nodes.map(x => ({x.node, x.name}))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the help of `Array.prototype.map` to map the array properties and keep only the required keys in the object:

```js
const data = {
    "nodes":[
        {"id":1,"node":"0","name":"pizza","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"node":"1","name":"pasta","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":3,"node":"2","name":"pie","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"id":1,"source":"0","target":"1","value":"451","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"source":"1","target":"3","value":"237","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ]
};
function transform(data){
    data.nodes = data.nodes.map(({node, name}) => ({node, name}));
    data.links = data.links.map(({source, target, value}) => ({source, target, value}));
    return data;
}
console.log(transform(data));
```

A more dynamic approach, where instead of hard-coding the props to keep, you supply it as a ES6 `Set` (for faster lookup) and map the nodes to the correct form:

```js
const data = {
    "nodes":[
        {"id":1,"node":"0","name":"pizza","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"node":"1","name":"pasta","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":3,"node":"2","name":"pie","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"id":1,"source":"0","target":"1","value":"451","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"},
        {"id":2,"source":"1","target":"3","value":"237","created_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01","updated_at":"2019-09-01 09:56:01"}
    ]
};

function transformDynamic(data, nodesToKeep, linksToKeep){
    data.nodes = data.nodes.map((ele) => {
       return Object.keys(ele).reduce((acc,key) => {
           if(nodesToKeep.has(key)){
              acc[key] = ele[key];           
           }
           return acc;
        }, {}); 
      })
    data.links =data.links.map((ele) => {
       return Object.keys(ele).reduce((acc,key) => {
           if(linksToKeep.has(key)){
              acc[key] = ele[key];           
           }
           return acc;
        }, {}); 
      });
    return data;
}
const nodesToKeep =  new Set(["node", "name"]);
const linksToKeep =  new Set(["ource", "target", "value"]);
console.log(transformDynamic(data, nodesToKeep, linksToKeep));
```